# How can I center text between the top and bottom of a div?

Tags: html, css

I want to align my text to the middle of my div, but I can't seem to make it work. How can I do this?

Thanks for the help!

```
<div style="height:40px;">Personal Information</div>
```

"Personal Information" should be centered between the top and bottom.

Comment: Please demonstrate your problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making **line-height** the size of the element. It will, however, only work if you have only one line of text.

Answer (score 5):

CSS:

```
myDiv
{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

INLINE:

```
<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">Personal Information</div>
```

UPDATE:

This works on JSFIDDLE...

```
div {
 display:table-cell;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 vertical-align:middle;
 background: red;
}
```

Comment: text-middle isn't a valid value for that property

Comment: doing vertical-align:middle; just aligns the div, not the text within it. sorry to make this so annoying; I thought there was an easy solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `table-cell` display style to achieve this:

**CSS**

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

CSS:

```
#outer {
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#outer[id] {
    display: table;
    position: static;
}

#middle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
} /* for explorer only */

#middle[id] {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: static;
}

#inner {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
    text-align: center;
} /* for explorer only */

#inner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

div.greenBorder {
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: ivory;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="outer" class="greenBorder">
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="inner" class="greenBorder"> center

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3NjUF/4/

This is with the height of 40px:
http://jsfiddle.net/3NjUF/5/

Answer (score 0):

try this(yellow is there to show that it is in the center of the div

```
  <html>
  <body>
  <div style="height:40px; background-color:yellow">
  <div style="position:absolute; top:50%; display:table">Personal Information</div>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a neat Trick of **margin:0 auto;** to align the contents inside the div to center.
In this case the following code should work fine,

**HTML:**

```
 <div style="height:40px;"><span>Personal Information</span></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 span
    { 
      width: 50%;
      margin: 20px auto;
      text-align: center;
      display:block
    }
```